# square tiled surfaces: Counting Saddle Connections vs Counting Square-Tiled Surfaces

Tags: nt.number-theory, gt.geometric-topology, ds.dynamical-systems

I am reading [Prime arithmetic Teichmuller discs in H(2)](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0401056) where they discuss the Siegel-Veech constant in a stratum $\mathcal{H}(2)$ of surfaces.  However I see two definitions of Siegel-Veech constant:

- $N(L)$ the number of parallel
  simple closed geodesics of length not exceeding $L$

In for genus greater than $1$ there are two separate definitions

- $N_{cyl}(L)$ the number of maximal cylinders made from parallel closed geodesics
- $N_{sc}(L)$ number of saddle connections connecting the singularities of the flat surface.

From what I gather, there are *generatic* Siegel Veech constants and constants for specific surfaces.  Fine.

Why does this paper suggest, is it equivalent to count square-tiled surfaces of a given size?